# How-to bootstrap your new blockchain network without centralised infrastructure

Tags: networking, libp2p, unstoppable

I am looking for best practices around this topic.

I liked how `webrtc-star` was easy to use, however I have not found anything in the rust ecosystem that is similar.

In my mind it would be great if there was a 'yellow pages' you could ask for the bootstrap nodes for chain X, something that could be run by all nodes to aid other networks getting user node 0+ booted.

Comment: could you use a common good parachain like Statemine on Kusama to store the latest list of bootnodes (along with a reputation) of each live parachain?

Comment: I can't find the ticket but I think that this is a feature that the substrate framework should be looking to support in the future.

Comment: This is a really interesting idea. Not only bootstrapping the seed nodes, but also the genesis files .

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, Substrate has not come up with a solution for this yet.

Substrate uses bootnodes to connect new nodes to the existing network, and from there, the networking protocol will connect the node to appropriate peers, and it shouldn't have any problems after that.

However, we are dependent currently on those bootnodes to initialize the connection to network peers.

However, this is something that has been talked about before. I think we just need the right solution to implement.